# getRange and setValue not working - Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm trying to create headers in a sheet on a given row. I was able to do that by using individual insertions from the code below, but I know that's not the best method:

```
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue("Date");
  sheet.getRange('B1').setValue("Impressions");
  sheet.getRange('C1').setValue("Clicks");
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue("CTR%");
  sheet.getRange('E1').setValue("Cost");
  sheet.getRange('F1').setValue("Average CPC");
  sheet.getRange('G1').setValue("Conversions");
  sheet.getRange('H1').setValue("Conversion Rate");
  sheet.getRange('I1').setValue("Cost Per Conversion");
```

I then tried to create an array to insert all at once, like below, but it didn't work:

```
  var colHeaders = [
  ["Date", "Impressions", "Clicks", "CTR%", "Cost", "Average CPC", "Conversions", "Conversion Rate", "Cost Per Conversion"]
  ];

    sheet.getRange("A1:I1").setValue(colHeaders);
   // var sheet already defined earlier and working fine
```

I've tried this based on [this Google docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) that provided this example:

```
var values = [
   [ "2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99" ]
 ];

 var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D2");
 range.setValues(values);
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use setValue**s**

Comment: Damn little detail. Right on target. Thanks Robin, it worked :D

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same type of problem but i figured out I was using the wrong class.

Please take a look at which class you are using when you declare your "sheet".

My mistake was using:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Instead of:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: oh, this was actually my issue too! I had `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`

Comment: This worked for me as well.
What's the difference between ActiveSheet and ActiveSpreadsheet anyways, the docs aren't great at explaining it in my opinion.